# App engine error. Process terminated due to exceeding quotas. Quotas page does not show any exceeded quotas

Tags: google-app-engine

After developing my app for a while with everything working fine, the App Engine backend stops taking requests with the error "Process terminated due to exceeding quotas." It won't take any more requests that day.

When I go to the AppEngine -> Quotas page, it doesn't show any quotas anywhere close to being used (see image).

[image: Quotas Page]
I suspect there is some quota being exceeded, because this only happens after working for several hours. If the error gave a clue as to which quota was being exceeded, I could look into that. Is there a way to find out why I am getting this quotas exceeded error, particularly which quota it is?

Logs:

[image: Logs]

GAE-specific quota page:

[image: GAE-specific quotas]

Comment: Can you post the complete text of an error message from the console logs?

Comment: The complete text was "Process terminated due to exceeding quotas.' I edited the post with a screenshot of the logs above.

Comment: Go backwards through the logs until you find those corresponding to the last few requests served by the app before being shutdown for quota exceeded. It's possible that one or more of these last requests errored due to the exceeded quota and thus the logs *might* contain details helping narrow down the search.

Comment: Just ruling out the obvious - make sure you're checking the quotas *while* your app is still shutdown - not after the daily quota reset. To be sure try a few requests to check if the app is still not working *after* you check the quotas.

Comment: There are no errors before the quotas exceeded error.

Comment: I am definitely not checking after the daily quota reset. This has happened twice now (the first time I thought it might just be a spurious app engine error). Both times, I've checked the quotas page immediately. I've also tried subsequent requests, and with different API methods, and all throw a the quotas exceeded error.

Comment: The quota page you're checking is the IAM & Admin one, which is supposed to be an aggregate from all Cloud products. Check also the GAE-specific one (in the App Engine menu): https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails. Just in case the aggregation missed something :)

Comment: I actually checked the GAE-specific one first. Nothing is over there either. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120383/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-jay-crosley).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 28.01 Frontend Instance Hours on the GAE specific quota page is awfully close to the 28 free daily Frontend Instance Hours.

Make sure you have billing enabled **and** set an acceptable daily spending limit set to allow your app to go over those free 28h/day.

From [Enabling billing and setting a spending limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/#billing):

> 1. Select a project and enable billing for your project.
>
>    - In the Cloud Platform Console, go to the [Billing Overview page](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/settings).
>    - If prompted, create a new billing account. Otherwise, select a billing account to associate with your project.
>        If billing is already enabled, then the billing account for the project is listed.
>
> After you enable billing, there is no limit to the amount you might be
>   charged until you set a daily spending limit. It's a good idea to
>   specify a spending limit to gain more control over application costs.
>
> 2. Create or change the spending limit.
>
>    - Go to the [Application settings](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/appengine/settings).
>    - Click Edit and specify a spending limit. Click Save.
>
> The spending limit only applies to [App Engine resources](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#cost_resource) for the
>   selected project:
>
> - You may still be charged for other Google Cloud Platform resources.
> - If you have multiple projects, you may want to set the spending limit for each project.
>
> When you increase the daily spending limit, the new limit takes effect
>   immediately.
>
> For more information, see [Spending Limits](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#spending_limit).

Comment: Billing was turned on, and I had a monthly budget, but I had not set the daily spending limit in the App Engine Application Settings. By default, it's still using the free tier, which has certain quotas (such as the instance hours) which are not apparent on the quotas page.